# Why aren't my GameKit (Game Center) achievements working?

Tags: ios, ios7, gamekit

I'm trying to add achievements to my game, but first testing the waters with a test app to avoid making mistakes on iTunesConnect for a production app.

I've added all the libraries, set up leaderboards and an achievement on iTunesConnect, and even tested it to WORK with both scores and the achievement. So, I tried adding some more achievements. They all have unique string IDs and are all listed on iTunesConnect associated with the correct app. Through troubleshooting, I even went into the "current" app version (it's not released on the app store) and enabled all leaderboards and achievements successfully for the app version. However, the ONLY achievement that works is the original one. Additionally, I tried changing the description string and achievement points for the first achievement, but that hasn't updated either.

I've tested this through the game center app, checking to see what achievements and leaderboards are listed, enabling the game center view controller in app to check from there, and even used the following code to see what achievements are accessible

```
 [GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"achs: %@", descriptions);
}];
```

In every case, the only achievement that shows is the first one, with the FIRST version of the description string and the first number of achievement points.

In reporting scores, I've made sure to check the errors and they all come back as nil, regardless of what achievement they are submitting.

I'm suspecting there's some sort of caching function going on with iTunesConnect and it's not updating to the newest version of the achievements, but I really have no clue. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Two days after I started having the issue, I decided to fire up the app and see if I could deduce anything else... Suddenly, it all worked. Does it seriously take 1+ days to get achievements and scores to update and work?! That hardly seems conducive to a development environment...

Comment: The +loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler class method only returns achievements that have progress on them, so keep that in mind when testing your code. There is certainly a delay with communication from iTunes Connect. This also affects achievement icons and descriptions when altered, not just new entries. It can create a bit of a headache when troubleshooting achievements/leaderboards.

Comment: That's why I used the description variant, + loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler which returns all achievements and their info. And the delay isn't an issue - it's the the data wasn't updating on the server. I'm still assuming caching issues.